# Autowired object is getting null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot for my application. I am defining JNDI name in the `application.properties` file.

When I am trying to get `JdbcTemplate` in below class, its `null`:

```
@Configuration
public class DemoClass
{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Bean
    private DataSource getDS(){
        return template.getDataSource(); //NPE
    }
}
```

Another Class

```
@Component
public class SecondClass {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    public void show(){
        template.getDataSource(): // Working Fine
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide your application properties and boot configuration as well. Without this info nobody can help you

Comment: The jdbc template depends upon the datasource. Pulling the datasource out of the template doesn't make sense. Just autowire the datasource if that is what you need.

Comment: Check your jndi name present in application properties with what is configured on application server. Also check your datasource configuration on application server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this configured by default.. In case it is not, then maybe you can try configuring it yourself:

```
@Autowired
DataSoure dataSource;

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
  return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

in any case if you need only the `DataSource`, I think it is auto-configured by Spring Boot so you can autowire it directly when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Repository
public class DataRepository {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }


    public int updateCandidate() {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.update("update .... from table where ....");
    }
}
```

- application.properties

  database connection details

  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:***`

  `spring.datasource.username=Scott`

  `spring.datasource.password=Tiger`

  `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

  `spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=1`

  `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1`

  `spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=1`

  `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=1`

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a NPE at getDS.  This means JdbcTemplate hasn't been injected yet, maybe it couldn't be injected.

Give spring a hint at bean dependencies by

```
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
    }
```

Or

```
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("template")
    public DataSouce getDS(){
        return template.getDataSource();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `@Autowired` sets `required=true` so the `DemoClass` should not be constructed by Spring.

Most likely you are creating `new DemoClass()` or disabled the annotation config altogether and the `DemoClass` class is registered manually e.g. using XML.

Instead ensure that the `DemoClass` class is discovered using Spring's component scan e.g. using `@SpringBootApplication` or `@ComponentScan` e.g. as per [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/).